# Some attributes get removed when fetching HTML files from Spring Boot API in Angular 5 app

Tags: java, html, angular, rest, spring-boot

When fetching a HTML file from Spring Boot back-end via its API with Angular 4 app on the front-end, HTML tag attributes of type `id`, `name`, `data-*` are stripped away, but `class` attribute type remains. What's the reason for this, as I can't seem to find it?

Comment: Angular HttpClient definately isn't doing that, it doesn't touch any html you get, it treats is as plain text ie just a string. If you inspect the response in browser dev tools, the attributes are already stripped on server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the attrs are stripped when you bind to the innerHTML of an element in a template, it seems those attributes are not allowed by the sanitizer. Probably mostly because they're not presentionally useful in an Angular app. I don't know if `id` and `data` are considered potentially unsafe too. I know forms, inputs, buttons etc. are so `name` is useless.

The allowed attrs are listed in html_sanitizer.ts ([full source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts)):

```
const HTML_ATTRS = tagSet('abbr,accesskey,align,alt,autoplay,axis,bgcolor,border,cellpadding,cellspacing,class,clear,color,cols,colspan,' 
+ 'compact,controls,coords,datetime,default,dir,download,face,headers,height,hidden,hreflang,hspace,' +   'ismap,itemscope,itemprop,kind,label,lang,language,loop,media,muted,nohref,nowrap,open,preload,rel,rev,role,rows,rowspan,rules,' +    'scope,scrolling,shape,size,sizes,span,srclang,start,summary,tabindex,target,title,translate,type,usemap,' +
    'valign,value,vspace,width');
```

If you really need id, name or data attributes (why would you really?) and can trust your html 110%, ie. it's not originated from any user input or you have already sanitized it serverside, you can call DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml() with it before binding (or in a pipe) to leave the html untouched.